# Check if row modified in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and I'm performing a bulk update for only one column with textbox. But before update I need to check the values of that textbox for entire gridview and if the values aren't changed I need to provide an alert stating "Make change to field to update".

Can anyone suggest me some options?

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
            {
               string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
               string strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
               string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;                                     
               {
                   //my update query
               }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about checking every Textbox's value in the gridview or just a single one ?

Comment: @HarveySpecter - About every textbox values in gridview.

Comment: One approach is Load the Data in your List/DataTable and validate every row.

Comment: In that case, you might have to store the original values of each textbox and in the next step, loop it for all rows and compare them.

Comment: @HarveySpecter for that, you can load data in a local variable like List/DataTable and compare the data with your data in Grid.

Comment: @SelvaTS - Indeed. Though it would be a performance hit, but since the OP wants.

Comment: @SelvaTS - yeah probably I can load the data into a datatable and how can I compare them with which datasource.

Comment: @Michael - Check my answer below. That should give you an idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A much simpler method will be to add an `asp:HiddenField` to your ItemTemplate and compare the value for each row.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("blah") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
```

Now all you need is to compare that value with the textbox value in each row in code-behind like this.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var isAnyRowUpdated = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
        {
            string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
            string strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
            string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;
            string strOldValue = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnOldValue")).Value;
            if (strValue != strOldValue)
            {
                isAnyRowUpdated = true;
                //update procedure here.
            }
        }
        //now check if the flag is still false
        //that means no rows are changed
        if(!isAnyRowUpdated)
        {
            //alert no rows are updated
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

I hope the code is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe the above code helps to update only row which have been modified. But I only need to alert if no rows are modified in the gridview.

Comment: oh you need to alert if no rows are modified and save the modified rows in all other cases?

Comment: yes thats right. I only need to alert if no rows are modified.

Comment: But if the very first row has same values the alert pops up . Shouldn't the alert come after looping through all gridview rows.

Comment: sorry man. the check should be outside the loop. my bad. damn typo :)

Comment: What a great, straightforward solution! I'm using this in my application and it works perfectly! Thank you codeandcloud!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can try to use [DataGridView.RowValidating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx) and check if [IsCurrentRowDirty](http://DataGridView.IsCurrentRowDirty%20Property) Property is changed</strike>

> IsCurrentRowDirty Property Gets a value indicating whether the current
>   row has uncommitted changes.

**EDIT:-**

The above works in Winforms; in Asp.net there is no such method, you have to load the data in a object and then you have to validate.

You can check [Updating Only Changed Rows Using GridView Control](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/05/22/122322.aspx)

Comment: OP asked in ASP.Net `Gridview` not in WinForms `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing to do here to load your original data into a `DataTable` and then compare the `GridView` rows, one by one in a loop for that particular Column, which in your case is the `TextBox` column. For comparing the `DataTable` with the `GridView`, you can try something like this :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in Grd.Rows)
{
   TextBox txtAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAmount");
   string Id = Grd.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      if (Id == dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString())
      {
         //do your logic here.
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the conversation, I have provided some pseudo logic. You can implement your own code using this.

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = LoadData(); //Load the data from DB
            EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> enumerableDt = dt.AsEnumerable();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
            {
                string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
                string strGroup = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblGrp")).Text;
                string strValue = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue")).Text;

                DataRow dr = enumerableDt.Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID") == strID).FirstOrDefault(); //Change your condition accordingly 

                if (dr["Value"].ToString().ToUpper() != strValue.Trim().ToUpper()) //Change your condition here
                {
                    //Do your updated data logic here
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do your not updated data logic here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check them against the datakey value for the corresponding item.

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Response, ...

foreach (GridDataItem item in FTReport.MasterTableView.Items)
{
  string ResponseValue = tbResponse.Text;
  if (item.GetDataKeyValue("Response").ToString() != ResponseValue)
  {
    do something;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use onrowdatabound property of gridview. Inside it, use:

```
 protected void GridLocation_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
   (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
        // here you can check your textbox values
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is `RowDataBound`. OP is asking for validation before `GridView` is bind again.

Comment: Isn't DataControlRowState.Edit used only for rowedit in gridview, because I don't have editrow property and I'm using bulkupdate. Please correct me if I'm wrong.